# Looping through array/object with no key names only indexes

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I've stored an array inside of my database using `json_encode` and ran `json_decode` on it when I want to retrieve it back out, however I am unable to run a `foreach` on it to access the image URL's that I need to display in my view.

Here is the result from the following `$new_invoices = json_decode($invoices); var_dump($new_invoices);`

This outputs:

```
array(2) { 
   [0]=> string(66) "/images/uploaded-invoices/1-logo-square-highres.png-1482788616.png" 
   [1]=> string(58) "/images/uploaded-invoices/1-logo-square.png-1482788616.png" 
}
```

I have been trying to grab the image URL's out of this using the following statement:

```
foreach ($new_invoices as $value) {
     echo($value);
}
```

This keeps throwing `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Is there a way to loop through and grab those URL's?

Comment: The code looks fine to me. If you are getting an array in your var_dump then it should be a valid foreach argument.

Comment: based on the code you provided it should work

Comment: `$new_invoices = json_decode($invoices, true); `

Comment: @Eugen The second argument only makes a difference for objects, not arrays and strings.

Comment: What seems weird about the structure. It's just an array with two strings in it.

Comment: Why are you storing an array in a single column of the table? Normalize your schema so each element is in a different row of a related table.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear where the error is. You are trying to loop a StdClass object.
When you call json_decode() it will parse the string and return an object. If what you need is an array, then supply - true - as the second argument.

json_decode($invoices, true);

The rest of your code should work fine.

Comment: I've also tried using `json_decode($invoices, true);` but it is still throwing the same error. I think I will just create a related table to store these in.